# How application like Android Protector works - i found its reading logcat to detect application launch, but how to lock execution?

Tags: android

Since few days i was wondering how App like [Android Protector](http://www.ruimaninfo.com/details/approtect.jsp) actually works.

My main concern was on how to detect a particular application is being launched and how to lock the execution for a while untill user enters unlock key(gesture pattern or password).

As [one of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838546/androidhow-does-application-protector-app-works/4841413#4841413)  to the question [Android: how does application Protector app work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838546/androidhow-does-application-protector-app-works), i  found it is reading logcat log to detect the Package Name and Process Id.

I am quite sure that these application locks the execution of another applicaiton - as seen in DDMS.

But still wondering how to lock the execution of App. I found they are using some native libaries. But could not found what exactly going on there.

Is there any clue for this ?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, they aren't "locking" the app : thanks to the [SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW) permission, they are able to display a window on top of the candidate.