# turn off recent apps button or clear list?

Tags: android, android-widget

Is there any way to either turn off the recent apps button in android 3.0 (I have a xoom) or clear the list? I have not found one so far.
It breaks my app protector program and allows people to circumvent the app password if its in the list. (like my gmail)
If not, does someone have a confirmed app protector program that accounts for this and works in android 3.0?

Comment: please make your question more clear...

Comment: I wanted to close all running recent applications from my application. How can I close all recent opened applications?

Comment: AFAIK closing an application does not remove it from recent apps. Try it yourself, go to applications and Force Stop a recent app. Also, you might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838546/androidhow-does-application-protector-app-works if you haven't already

Answer (score 0):

Why not add android:noHistory="true" to your manifest for the activity?