# Lock other apps while my application runs

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: how does application Protector app work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838546/android-how-does-application-protector-app-work)

Restated: Apps like APP Lock and Smart App Protector somehow take the link between the application's icon and the app and put a subroutine (?) in between them so a password is required before the application will launch instead of the app launching immediately after the icon is pressed. How is that accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

By writing a custom system image and flashing it onto an unlocked device. What you're describing is largely considered malware behavior and is not permitted by the base Android system.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You're familiar with Smart App Protector and APP Lock?  They take all apps that you authorize and password protect them so they can only be launched with the password of your choice.  I need to do that. I can't use them, because there is additional functionality I need that they don't provide, so I'm writing my own custom app.  So what I need to know is, how do I tell Android to only launch certain apps if the correct password is provided?

Comment: The mechanisms many of those apps used no longer work under Android 4.1 (Jellybean). To implement this sort of thing correctly it would involve additions to the device administration APIs at the platform level: (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

Comment: We need a Linux type setup where the system user can create a single local user who is chrooted and only has access to a limited number of apps as defined by the system user.  Sadly our employees were using the phones for everything except what they were supposed to be used for.  I installed Smart App Protector, but they figured out they could uninstall it by booting into safe mode.  I'll inform the company to go ahead and remove the Android phones and go with the propitiatory tablets, which are Windows based. The only programs installed are the ones we need for the business. Thanks!

Comment: @user1610260: it's sound to me that the right solution for you problems is working with some MDM services provider. as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not considered very ethical by the Android community and there are chances that your app would end up being listed as a malware.

Anyway, it could be done by making your application go Fullscreen and disabling/overriding the Home button and the Back button. In extreme cases, you could also define a BroadcastReceiver to automatically start the application when the phone is restarted and booting is complete.

That way, the only thing that can run on the device would be your app as even if the user shuts down the device, the BroadcastReceiver will start the app as soon as the device is restarted again.

**Note :** Overriding the Home button is not possible post ICS versions but you can still restrict the user to only your application by defining it as a Launcher, so that pressing the Home button just restarts your application instead of taking the user to the home screen.

Comment: You can't override the home button, for security reasons

Comment: @Ahmad : Oh yes! You CAN! I have done it in one of my apps.

Comment: Post ICS, it has become a little more difficult. The HomeButton can't overridden in ICS but you can always mark your application as a Launcher. So, first time the device asks you which launcher you want to run when the Home button is pressed. If you select the "by default" for your application, every time the Home button is pressed, it would just restart the application. The user is thus restricted to ONLY that application and can no way leave it!

Comment: None of this stops an app from running, simply from being launched in the usual ways but there are other means to run an app, for example via ADB.  Thankfully, as others have said, apps are not allowed to control other apps they have no contract with.

Comment: @swayam wow. Never tought about that. Clever... sorry I have to take back my previous comment :)

Comment: Well, if you bring ADB into the picture then everything is possible. But, generally speaking, I don't think too many of the daily application users are coders and hence running commands directly from the ADB would seem pretty far-fetched for them. I totally agree with whatever @Simon said, but I was simply talking about normal daily users, not developers. :)

Comment: The user setting an app as their launcher is quite a bit different from overriding the home button, as it is their explicit choice to do so. Overriding the home button from application code is not permitted. There are also a number of ways to reboot into Safe Mode depending on the device, which disables all 3rd party apps and would allow a user to "escape" from a misbehaving launcher replacement.

Comment: @adamp : Agree with you totally! But by "overriding the Home button", I just meant that the Home button would not do what it is usually supposed to and if the user sets it as a launcher once, then he can't exit the app (by the usual means). Plus, before ICS, HomeButton could be overridden in the code and I believe we are not talking about ICS only, or are we ?

Comment: The window schemes you're thinking of didn't do anything to override the button itself.

Comment: My aim was to restrict the user to only my application so that he can't come out of it to start another application and it was achieved.

Comment: And the bug that let it pass has since been fixed. ;) If your app does this maliciously on a device that still has the bug, it's a great way to run afoul of the Play Store's developer agreement and get your app booted from the store.

Comment: +1 from my side for that! Hahaha! Yes indeed it would have my app booted from the store. But I never said that I had such an app on the store. ;)

Comment: @adamp : on a more serious note, which bug fix are you talking about ? Can I no longer declare my app as a launcher and restrict the user to it ?

Comment: You can still have your app respond to the launcher intent and use the normal "set as default" mechanism. If you deliberately try to keep the device's owner from using the rest of the device you're very likely to run afoul of Play Store policies. Apps like ToddlerLock that use a mechanism where the device's owner can get out but a child, for example, cannot, tend to be ok.

Comment: Well, if the user chooses to set my application as default, he can't really blame me for that, can he ?! :D Plus, I had to get this workaround as the client demanded that only this application runs on his system.

Comment: @swayam What if another app (running in background) sets up a BroadcastReceiver, and from that it starts an Activity ? Does your app blocks that activity from starting ?

Comment: No, in that case my mechanism would fail. As would running applications via the ADB. It is just a workaround that works in most cases. Never claimed that it is fool proof. :)